# What does Letter/alphabet represents in error "“Error: Unknown provider: bProvider <- b”?"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was playing around with some basic angular. At some point I got a error message saying

> "Error: Unknown provider: bProvider <- b".

I figured out that I didn't inject a dependency, but what does "b" represents?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/2gpf8Ea-PFQ

Answer (score 0):

From the article:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/2gpf8Ea-PFQ

> The problem is your production code is minifying your opentaste.js.
>
> One trick minifiers use is to rename variables and arguments inside
>   functions, because their scope can be easily reasoned about, so
>   renaming them is of no consequence (except saving bytes).
>
> The problem is angular actually uses the names of function parameters
>   (by actually reading your code) to determine what dependencies need to
>   be loaded. If your controller has a $scope argument, it passes the
>   appropriate value. The problem is the minifier changed '$scope' to 'b'
>   (or something meaningful to something meaningless)
>
> Read http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di, specifically $inject
>   Annotation and Inline Annotation. These are methods for defining
>   explicitly what your arguments/dependencies are, in such a way that
>   angular doesn't have to read your code to figure it out. These
>   techniques work because the minifier won't change the values of
>   strings for obvious reasons.
>
> It's a bit more code, a bit less 'magic', but necessary if you plan to
>   minify your AngularJS code.